# Repairing git branch: refs now show refs/remotes/branch and refs/remotes/origin/branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase, git-remote

I screwed up a local branch on my computer by rebasing it to some other branch. I wanted to rebase but I didn't switch to the branch I wanted to rebase, and as a result I screwed up `somebranch`. I had no idea how to undo my rebase screwup in `somebranch` (if anyone knows it would be good to know for the future) so I decided that since I have `somebranch` on github I would just delete it locally and then pull it from github. I don't know what I did but I screwed that up too. Eventually I found what I believe to be the right commands to recreate a deleted local branch by pulling it in from my remote origin:

```
git fetch origin somebranch:refs/remotes/somebranch
git checkout -b somebranch --track origin/somebranch
```

In gitk I can see there are three things now:
*somebranch, remotes/somebranch, remotes/origin/somebranch*

but all my other branches only show a local and one remote. example:
*someotherbranch, remotes/origin/someotherbranch*

I ran `git for-each-ref` and both ref/remotes/somebranch and ref/remotes/origin/somebranch point to the same commit.

My question is what is the difference between the two and how do I get rid of the ref/remotes/somebranch. I tried `git update-ref -d remotes/somebranch` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. Just add 'refs':

```
git update-ref -d refs/remotes/somebranch
```

You can confirm it's gone by issuing, in the top level of the repository:

```
ls .git/refs/remotes
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked. When I run `git remote show origin` I see that it says `Local branch configured for 'git pull': somebranch merges with remote somebranch`. But none of my other branches have an entry for 'git pull'. Is that normal?

Comment: Depends entirely on how you set them up to begin with. If you want to set an "upstream" branch, which will enable `git pull`, this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2286030/877115